# simulate clock-skew scenario

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I met this clock-skew correction error(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/clock-skew-correction/) I'm getting from S3 getobject call from Lambda, and I have made a fix to the issue(this is in Nodejs)and right now is writing the unit test for the function.

Basically I'm trying to simulate the scenario where the client has a time difference of 15+ mins with S3, I have search for few S3 mock up library, but have no clue how to do so.

I'm using mocha as the test framework

Comment: *"I have made a fix"* -- what did you fix, and how?  The "fix" for this is setting your machine's clock and time zone correctly, which -- arguably -- isn't something you should be unit testing in your code that accesses S3, because that isn't where this problem comes from.

Comment: By specifying correctClockSkew setting and a retry function. Right now I'm trying to set up a web server using nock to intercept the S3 https get and return the wrong status code intentionally, if the the retry functions gets call, then it's pass.

Comment: Wait a minute... *"error I'm getting from S3 getobject call from Lambda"* ...?  That should be impossible.  The Lambda clock and the S3 clock should never be skewed.

Comment: I'm calling the s3.getObject() inside a Lambda and getting the error from S3. The scenario was that the client initiated the call to the Lambda with the wrong timestamp(probably 15+ mins behind) and ended up with a clock skewed error.

Comment: I would suggest that you should not be trusting a timestamp provided by the client.  You may want to provide more detail about exactly what you're doing here, at the risk of solving the wrong problem or exposing yourself to potential manipulation and vulnerabilities.